# Convert Drive to NTFS from FAT32

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs, cmd.exe

I'm having strange problems converting my HDD from FAT32 to a NTFS file storage.

I first ran `chkdsk N: /f` and came up no problems so I ran `convert N: /fs:ntfs` but it tells me there is a problem.

[image: NTFS Conversion Fault]

How can I fix this problem? I have tried ejecting my HDD and trying again but had no luck.

Comment: I think if you reboot Windows, it will do the `AUTOCHK` and the `dirty` bit will be cleared.

Comment: @LittleHelper So I just need to reboot? `AUTOCHK` does it by itself?

Comment: While Windows is booting, it checks for that particular `dirty` bit and if it's set to true, it will check the drive. So yeah, you just need to reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run **Chkdsk N: /r** command to mark the sector unusable if its bad sector and recovers readable information.